# How can I pass file as stdin to `php artisan my_custom_command`?

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I'm doing `php artisan my_custom_command < file` but it just gives `the input device is not a TTY`

How else can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to pass in a file path, the contents of a file, or user input?

Comment: Pass the name of the file and access/open/manipulate it within the code using Laravel's file structure logic.

Comment: @aynber contents of a file as stdin

Comment: It would probably be better to pass the file name/path in via an [argument or option](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#defining-input-expectations), then have PHP open the file to get the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you try to read from stdin. You can try `php://stdin`,

> php://stdin, php://stdout and php://stderr allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process. [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Here is what I tried,

```
// command signature
protected $signature = 'read:stdin';

public function handle()
{
    $in = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    while( $line = fgets( $in ) ) {
        $this->info("Received: " . $line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can redirect any file like this:

```
php artisan read:stdin <file
```

And even you can try Heredoc like this,

```
php artisan read:stdin <<EOF
heredoc> Hello
heredoc> this is Heredoc
heredoc> EOF
Received: Hello

Received: this is Heredoc
```

Also, reading from standard input:

```
php artisan read:stdin </dev/stdin
Hello
Received: Hello

This is standard input
Received: This is standard input
```